# No such file or directory when trying to run script in github actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a github action setup and I need to run some local script named `/deploy_container_app.sh` located at the `./scripts` (I attached the the file stracture in an image below).
For some reason I don't understand github says the file is not found even though when I run `ls -la`the file is showing.

this is the log from github
[image]

this is my yaml

```
on: [push]
name: Linux_Container_Workflow

jobs:
    build-and-deploy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
        # checkout the repo
        - name: 'Checkout GitHub Action'
          uses: actions/checkout@v4

        - name: 'Login via Azure CLI'
          uses: azure/login@v1
          with:
            creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

        - name: 'Build and push image'
          uses: azure/docker-login@v1
          with:
            login-server: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}
            username: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
            password: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}
        - run: |
            echo ${{ vars.REPOSITORY_NAME}} 
            docker build . -t ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}/${{ vars.REPOSITORY_NAME}}:${{ github.ref_name }}-${{ github.run_number }}
            docker push ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}/${{ vars.REPOSITORY_NAME}}:${{ github.ref_name }}-${{ github.run_number }}


        - name: Deploy Container App with Custom Script
          working-directory: scripts
          run: |
            ls -la # list files to debug
            ./deploy_container_app.sh # execute the script
          shell: bash
          env:
            REPOSITORY_NAME: ${{ secrets.REPOSITORY_NAME }}
            REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}
            ROBOFLOW_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.ROBOFLOW_API_KEY }}
            CALLER_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.CALLER_API_KEY }}
            CALLER_SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.CALLER_SECRET_KEY }}
```

this is my file stracture:
[image]

Comment: Does it work by using its relative path and without `working-directory`?

Comment: nope, same issue. tried that before trying the `working-directory`

Comment: What does your directory structure look like? Please add that in your question.

Comment: added the file stracture to the post

Comment: maybe need to add `chmod +x ./deploy_container_app.sh`?

Comment: you can see in the ls -la output that the file is executable?

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.
The filename somehow had a space in the filename and therefor when trying to execute it with the "correct" indeed no file was found .